# Can a Pivot Resolve this?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

I have a table with 3 columns that describe an event: `Location`, `StartTime` and `DayofWeek`.  `Location` can host the event on any `DayofWeek` and one or more that one `StartTime` on a Day or no `StartTime` on any `DayofWeek`.

[image: Event]

The result table that I need should have 8 columns:  `Location`, `MonTime`, `TueTime`, `WedTime`,  `ThuTime`, `FriTime`, `SatTime` and `SunTime`.If there is more than one time on one or more days for a certain location, there will be a row fot every different `StartTime` against `Location`.

[image: Weekdays pivot]

I have tried a pivot with `MAX` and `MIN` which sort of resolves the problem but only if there is a max of 2 different times on a day.

I also tried a Cursor loop with `INSERT` and dynamic `UPDATE` but that was a failure.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by first assigning a ranking to each of your "*StartTime*" partitioned by "*Location*" and "*DayofWeek*". Then you can easily apply your pivot with the `CASE` statements and the aggregation on both your "*Location*" and just computed ranking number:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location, DayofWeek ORDER BY StartTime) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT Location AS Site,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DayofWeek='Mon' THEN StartTime END) AS MonTime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DayofWeek='Tue' THEN StartTime END) AS TueTime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DayofWeek='Wed' THEN StartTime END) AS WedTime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DayofWeek='Thu' THEN StartTime END) AS ThuTime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DayofWeek='Fri' THEN StartTime END) AS FriTime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DayofWeek='Sat' THEN StartTime END) AS SatTime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DayofWeek='Sun' THEN StartTime END) AS SunTime
FROM cte
GROUP BY Location, 
         rn
ORDER BY Site, 
         MonTime
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efff7067f777c109cd48949f9e2967db).

Comment: This perfect too.  Thank you. Which method would be the fastest (PIVOT or CASE) as there are about 1000 timed events in my source table?

Comment: This method is 25% more efficient than using the `PIVOT` function. See here for details about performance comparison >> https://sqlsunday.com/2016/01/29/pivot-unpivot-and-performance/

Comment: Anyways if you want to be sure apart from theory, really you should look at the execution plan using the `ANALYZE` statement.

Comment: 25% ?  ... Absolute nonsense.  Some people simply don't like PIVOT and that's OK, but there is no need for hyperbole or anecdotal observations.   In my head it is just another tool in the belt.    That said it you look at the execution plan,  PIVOT has a relative to batch cost of 41% while the conditional aggregation has a cost of 59%.

Comment: Those are not my words, I'm just reporting the value from the experimentation carried out at the link. But I agree that looking at the execution plan is the best way to check for perfomance comparison as the efficiency may probably change according to the available data. @JohnCappelletti

Comment: I tend to be wary of dogmas.  :)

Comment: @John Cappelletti  Thanks to both of you for the solution and the additional advice.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want the PIVOT.

Note:  Without a proper sequence (date, identity etc) both approaches will "FILL-IN" the matrix from top down.

```
Select Location
      ,MonTime = Mon
      ,TueTime = Tue
      ,WedTime = Wed
      ,ThuTime = Thu
      ,FriTime = Fri
      ,SatTime = Sat
      ,SunTime = Sun
 From (
        Select *,RN = row_number() over (partition by Location,DayofWeek Order by StartTime)
         From YourTable
      ) Src
 Pivot ( max( StartTime ) for DayofWeek in ([Mon],[Tue],[Wed],[Thu],[Fri],[Sat],[Sun]  ) ) pvt
 Order by Location
```

Results

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. It's helped me to understand Pivots a lot better. I'll experiment adding dates. Thank you

Comment: @Davey Always happy to help.  PIVOT and Conditional Aggregation both have merits.   Lemon's assertion that his approach is 25% more efficient is simply false.   That said, Condition Aggregation does offers a more flexibility.